# How to partition by a customized sum value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns: customer_id, event_date_time

I'd like to figure out how many times a customer triggers an event every 12 hours from the start of an event. **In other words, aggregate the time between events for up to 12 hours by customer.**

For example, if a customer triggers an event (in order) at noon, 1:30pm, 5pm, 2am, and 3pm, I would want to return the noon, 2am, and 3pm record.

I've written this query:

```
select
    cust_id,
    event_datetime,
    nvl(24*(event_datetime - lag(event_datetime) over (partition BY cust_id ORDER BY event_datetime)),0) as difference
from
  tbl
```

I feel like I'm close with this. Is there a way to add something like

```
 over (partition BY cust_id, sum(difference)<12 ORDER BY event_datetime)
```

EDIT: I'm adding some sample data:

```
+---------+-----------------+-------------+---+
| cust_id | event_datetime  | DIFFERENCE  | X |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+---+
|       1 | 6/20/2015 23:35 | 0           | x |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 0:09  | 0.558611111 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 0:49  | 0.667777778 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 1:30  | 0.688333333 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 9:38  | 8.133055556 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 10:09 | 0.511111111 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 10:45 | 0.600555556 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 11:09 | 0.411111111 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 11:32 | 0.381666667 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 11:55 | 0.385       | x |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 12:18 | 0.383055556 |   |
|       1 | 6/21/2015 12:23 | 0.074444444 |   |
|       1 | 6/22/2015 10:01 | 21.63527778 | x |
|       1 | 6/22/2015 10:24 | 0.380555556 |   |
|       1 | 6/22/2015 10:46 | 0.373611111 |   |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+---+
```

The "x" are the records that should be pulled since they're the first records in the 12 hour block.

Comment: Make sure you tag the RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the first record in each 12-hour block where the blocks of time are defined by the first event time.

If so, you need to modify your query to get the difference from the *first * time for each customer.  The rest is just arithmetic.  The query would look something like this:

```
with t as (
    select cust_id, event_datetime,
           (24 * (event_datetime -
                  coalesce(min(event_datetime) over (partition by cust_id ), 0)
           ) as difference
    from tbl
   )
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by cust_id, floor(difference / 12)
                                order by difference) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's super close, but not working. Your assumptions are correct. I'll add some examples in the OP

Comment: @rogre . . . I'm not sure if the change I just made would fix the problem.  If not, please describe what the problem is.